# How can I get the list of all pages URLs including their shortlink IDs?

Tags: permalinks

I would like to get the list of all URLs from a wordpress installation. Nevertheless, I Don't want the full post titles in the permalink but I would like the shortlinks instead. I would like to get the following in the same fashion:

```
https://example.com/?p=123
https://example.com/?p=124
https://example.com/?p=125
https://example.com/?p=126
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this from the `guid` column in the `posts` table of your database.

[image: List of guids from database, eg http://wordpress.test/?p=1]

Comment: I ended up running the following mysql query: SELECT DISTINCT guid FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_status="publish" and post_type="post"

Answer (score 0):

Couple ways to go here, my friend.

**Plugin:**
All-in-SEO (https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/). Generates a sitemap.xml that should be mighty useful for your needs.

**Code:**
If you need an array of permalinks to work with later, I'd recommend you use The Loop (https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) to loop through all your posts, pages, etc. and feed the_permalink (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) in an array.

Something like this:

```
<?php
    // Not copy and paste safe, please read
    // This sets up what we want to fetch from the database
    // All the posts, pages, and any other custom post types
    // Setting 'posts_per_page' to -1 give you all the matches in the db
     $args = array('post_type' => array( 'post', 'page', 'any-other-custom-post-type'), 'posts_per_page' => -1 );

     // Go get what we want
     $WP_objects_I_will_loop_through = new WP_Query($args);

     //If there are any objects in the db that match our search...
     if ($WP_objects_I_will_loop_through->have_posts()):
        //loop through them and...
         while ($WP_objects_I_will_loop_through->have_posts()):
            //...Start with the first one, and then the next and....
             $WP_objects_I_will_loop_through->the_post();
             //...get the right post object each time through the loop
             global $post;
            // Create an array to fill with URL's and...
             $my_array_filled_with_urls = [];
             // Pop them in one at a time
             $my_array_filled_with_urls[] = get_permalink($post->ID);

         endwhile;
     endif;
     // Keeps you safe if you use this somewhere near another loop
     wp_reset_query();
```